# perl regex matching same line

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement, foreach, hashmap

The first `if ($line =~ ...)` statement is returning the correct match ($1), which is being assigned to num.

The second `if ($line =~ ...)` statement is not returning any value, and thus nothing is being assigned to the definitions hash. I tested this regex statement separately, and it does return the correct match ($1).

I would like `$definitions{$file}{$num}` to be assigned to the return value of the second regex expression.

Thanks for any help. I am a perl/regex beginner.

```
my $dir = "/.../...";
my %definitions;
my $num;

opendir (DIR, $dir) or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
        next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
        open FILE, "<$dir/$file" or die $!;
        my @lines = <FILE>;
            foreach my $line (@lines) {
                if ($line =~ m/\', (.*?)\, /g) {
                    $num = $1;
                }
                if ($line =~ m/\'(.*?)\'/g) { # no match is found
                    $definitions{$file}{$num} = $1; # nothing is assigned
                }
            }
        close FILE;
    }
closedir DIR;
```

**edit:**

example of data file: (other files are much longer, this is the shortest one)

('sodium cations', 169, 183), 
('ID 3006450 289000 - 440000', 10, 36)

I am trying to extract what is between the single quotes and assign it to definitions, and take the first number after that and assign it to num.

Comment: Can you provide an example line from the file?

Comment: What you are saying is that the second regex isn't finding the pattern on the line, in short.  Can you show us some data?  There are a number of other comments, but this is the first thing.

Comment: `if ($line =~ m/\', (.*?)\, /g)` instead `if ($line =~ m/\', (.*?)\, /)` and ` if ($line =~ m/\'(.*?)\'/g)` instead ` if ($line =~ m/\'(.*?)\'/)` It will work might be.

Comment: I may have not said it clearly: there is nothing with your regex that is wrong so to make it not match.  What means that your data may just not have that `'.*?'` pattern.  Also, note that `.*` matches _nothing_ as well, so if you have `''` first on the line then that's what you'll catch.

Comment: Shouldn't `$CDE_instances` be `$definitions` or vice versa?

Comment: *`not returning any value`* -- do you mean `undef` or just an empty string?

Comment: `if (//g)` makes no sense. `if (//g)` should be `if (//)`. `if (//g)` could very well be the source of your problem.

Comment: I extended the previous brief comment on `/g`, see the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question can't be fully answered until we see some data.

In the meanwhile here are some comments on the code.  First the program

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.012;   # so readdir assigns to $_ in  while (readdir $dh)

my %definitions;

my $dir = '/path/to/dir';
opendir my $dh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $!";

while (my $file = readdir($dh))
{
    next if $file =~ /^\./;
    next if -d $file;        # make sure we don't try to open() a dir

    open my $fh, '<', "$dir/$file" or die "Can't open $dir/$file: $!";

    while (my $line = <$fh>)
    {
        if (my ($num) = $line =~ m/', (.*?), / and    #' 
            my ($val) = $line =~ m/'(.*?)'/       )     
        {
            $definitions{$file}{$num} = $val;
        }   
    }   
    close $fh;
}    
close $dh;
```

It may well be that you can do both matches nicely in one regex. Please show us some data.

Comments

- Please *always* have `use warnings;`, and `use strict;`
- Extra indentation may seem helpful but it most often makes it harder to follow
- Use lexical filehandles, `my $fh` instead of `FILE` (etc) -- they are just better
- Since v5.12 [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) assigns to `$_` when used as `while (readdir $dh)`. It is then prudent to require at least that version, thus `use 5.012`. I include it in case this does get used
- We rarely need to read the file into an array first. Read line by line, `while (<$fh>)`
- *Declare in small scope.*  The global `$num` in posted code allows a bug: when the first regex fails but second matches, a value is assigned to the key `$num` found *previously*.  The reason is the use of separate `if`s for things with dependencies, but local `my $num` would help.
- Can assign from a match, `my ($var) = $string =~ /.../`, unless there is a specific reason to first test then assign.  Note parentheses, to impose the *list [context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context)* on the [match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) since in that context it returns the list of the matches. See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)
- Can declare and assign inside `if` condition, like you do with `while`. The variable is seen within that scope, just as it should be. This pulls the processing into its own block, usually making the code clearer. We need to see data for a possibly better way to do this.
- The `/g` makes no sense here, while it acts in a complex way. See comment at the end
- Extra escaping in regex: no need to escape `'` nor `,`
- The `while` loop can be written

  ```
  while (<$fh>) {
      if (my ($num) = /.../ and my ($val) = /.../)    ...
  ```

  utilizing the [$_ variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) which is regex's default, as it is for many other operations in Perl.

To venture into some guessing:

- The pattern `.*` also matches *nothing*, so if you have `''` before `'stuff'` on the line then your pattern `'(.*?)'` will match `''`, capturing an empty string.
- The second regex matches, but the first failed so there is no key to assign to. This agrees with your tests on regex alone. (You'd hear about it with `use warnings` in effect.)

---

The presence of `/g` in both regex is wrong and it is likely the direct error (but note the others). Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments.  From [Matching in list context in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

> In scalar context, each execution of `m//g` finds the next match, returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match.   [ ... ]

This is normally used in constructs like `while (/(...)/g) { ... }` where  scanning of the string at each iteration continues *from where it matched last*, looking for the *next match*. So one matches is found in each iteration and they are thus processed one at a time inside the loop.

The phrase "*finds the next match*" from docs hides complex behavior, which the two `if` conditions with `/g` seriously mess with. This can be seen by testing in a separate small script.

The behavior in the list context differs, `my @all_matches = /(...)/g;`. See docs.

Comment: Sometimes there's a reason to test then assign - if you're overwriting an existing variable, because no match means you're overwriting it with `undef`. (Which is what happens with the second match, rather than the first)

Comment: @Sobrique Yes, a good point. Corrected the statement, will reconsider the code. Thank you.

Comment: Re "*The `/g` makes no sense here*", And this is the cause of the OP's problem.

Comment: @ikegami  I thought of that, but my test still sticks the match into `$1` when I add `/g` ... will try more, thank you.  I don't know what `/g` does here (doesn't seem to jump over iterations)

Comment: That's because you don't have `if (//g)` like the OP does. Test: `perl -E'$_="\x27abc\x27, 123, "; say "!1" if /\x27, (.*?), /g; say "!2" if /\x27(.*?)\x27/g;'
`

Comment: @ikegami Thank you! I meant that _when I add_ `/g` my code doesn't reproduce error -- apparently I didn't correctly reproduce their two`if` in my test. I'll amend comments.  Btw, your one-liner just showed me how to use `'` in one-liner regex :))  Never thought of that, simple as it is :)

Comment: Can also replace `'` with `'\''`

Comment: @ikegami oh ... really. wow, they just continue.  thank you :)   That `/g` with two `if`s is _bad_ -- need it on _both_ for behavior to differ.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough response. My small problem was solved and I learned much more about perl from the discussion and will be utilizing your recommendations in the future.

Comment: just one question -- could you clarify the use of 5.012? Is it necessary?

Comment: @jelly You are welcome :)  There is quite a bit here, let me know if questions pop up later.  The `use 5.012` requires that it is at least that version of Perl.  This is needed to be able to use "_bare_" [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) in a `while` loop, so that it sets `$_` every time through, `while (readdir $dh) { say $_ }`.  That capability was introduced in version v5.12.  Your code assigns to a variable (`$file`) and thus doesn't use this, but I included the `use 5.012` guard just in case.

Comment: @jelly  Thanks for asking, this needed a comment I think. I added a little to the comment in code and added another bullet on this.  To answer more directly (in case the above didn't) -- for the code you have you don't need `use 5.012;`.  If the code is always going to run on versions later than v5.12 you don't need that statement either.